# How can I simulate a super capacitor in LTspice?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, simulation, boost, supercapacitor

I am trying to simulate a super capacitor in LTspice but it is not giving me the correct discharge time as it should be theoretically.

Has anyone also faced this issue? Please let me know how to simulate a super capacitor in LTspice.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! The capacitor is not the problem. What voltage did you charge it to?

Comment: This might not be related, but your `.model` statement doesn't do anything in your schematic.  You're defining a model called `Diode` so if you want to use it you have to change the values of your diodes from `D` to `Diode`.